# How To add Search Functionality Through All Columns in jquery Easy Ui combogrid

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jakarta-ee, datagrid

I have Created one combogrid using jquery easy ui ,and the code is

```
   $('#inputTextID').combogrid({
         url: '../Controller/getData.do',
         panelWidth:300,
         width:250,
         value:'14',
         idField:'id',
         textField:'value',
         columns:[[
              {field:'id',title:'Id',width:150},
              {field:'value',title:'Value',width:150},
              {field:'empName',title:'empName',width:150},
              {field:'empAddress',title:'empAddress',width:150}
          ]]
    });
```

Now in this code search traverse only considering  value column,i want add search funtionality considering all columns in grid,how can i?? please any one help me....
Want to consider remaing column also

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` option to override the default behaviour.

`$('#inputTextID').combogrid({
         url: '../Controller/getData.do',
         panelWidth:300,
         width:250,
         value:'14',
         idField:'id',
         textField:'value',
         columns:[[
              {field:'id',title:'Id',width:150},
              {field:'value',title:'Value',width:150},
              {field:'empName',title:'empName',width:150},
              {field:'empAddress',title:'empAddress',width:150}
          ]],
         filter:function(q, row) {
              //this will check in two columns...
              return (row['your_prop1'].indexOf(q)==0 || row['your_prop2'].indexOf(q)==0);
          }
    });`